# tesseract 5 wont recognize several no brainer single digits, any pointer would be very welcome

Tags: tesseract

here is a 7 that gets read as a T
[image: here is a 7 that gets read as a T]

here is a 2 that gets recognized as 'a'
[image: here is a 2 that gets recognized as 'a']

```
tesseract <file> <oout> --psm 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recognize the digits by using -l osd

```
tesseract fbW4p.png stdout -l osd --oem 3 --psm 7
7

tesseract CsF3c.png stdout -l osd --oem 3 --psm 7
2
```

Comment: ah yes, but now it wont recognize other digits that it was working with before :-(

Comment: Maybe if you attach the image, I can help.

Answer (score 0):

for detecting only digits try using:  `outputbase digits`, I hope this will help you!

Comment: i did that, didnt help